# how to show strings in other languages

Tags: android, string, textview

I have created a game like guess the emoji

```
private TextView          txtDashes;
private int      position;
private int stage;
private int position=0;
private String dashes;
```

...

```
       if(stage==2){
        // dashes = dashes + "---------";   
       dashes = dashes + "----- ---";   


     }
     else {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.length(); i++) {
            dashes = dashes + "-";

        }

     }
    txtDashes.setText(dashes);
```

in this code i display ----- --- in the TextView and all the things are correct
but in the code below i have problem with displaying dashes in text view in sage 2

```
 public void letterOnClickListener(View view) {
    Button btn = (Button) view;
    btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    invisibleButtons.add(btn);
    char letter = btn.getText().toString().toCharArray()[0];

        char[] dashesArray = txtDashes.getText().toString().toCharArray();
        char[] charArray = currentWord.toCharArray();
        if(stage==2)
        {
            dashesArray[3]=' ';
        /*  k++;
            if(k==1)
            {
                dash = dash + "--- -----"; 
                txtDashes.setText(dash);
            }*/


            if(position==3)
            {
            //  dashesArray[3]=' ';
                nCorrect++;
                position++;

            }
            if (charArray[position] == letter) {
                nCorrect++;
            }


            if(position!=3){
            dashesArray[position] = letter;
            position ++;
            txtDashes.setText(new String(dashesArray));
        }}
```

i want replace dashes with letters and the word has 2 syllables for example (کره جنوبی) and i want to show in text view but when i click on the button in keyboard its the result in textview :
--- - --ک
i think its because of the language that string is displaying left to right 
how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Where do the `position` come from? Please reveal complete code. From your code, I think the result is the same no matter the text is ltr or rtl

Comment: @Minhtdh position=0;